# How to render absoulute element inside ListView or FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist

Here's a fun one i've been poking at for while:

I have a FlatList (same issue with ListView) and I want to render an element INSIDE the internal scrolling container with the following characteristics:

- Absolutely Positioned (thus having no effect on position of list elements)
- Position XX distance from top (`translateY` or `top`)
- zIndex (above list elements)

The use case is i'm rendering a day view calendar grid with a horizontal bar at the current time position fixed at X distance from the beginning of the internal scrollview so it appears as the user scrolls pass that position.

So far i've tried wrapping wrapping FlatList/ListView with another ScrollView... also tried rendering this element as the header element which only works while the header/footer are visible (trashed when out of view).

Any and all ideas welcomed. :)

Thanks

Screenshot Below (red bar is what i'm trying to render):

[image: Day View Calendar Grid]

Comment: Any special reason you don't just make a sibling view to the `ListView` with a higher `zIndex`?

Comment: hmm.. You mean a ListView just for the bar? I've tried a sibling ScrollView (since it's just one element) but how would we sync their scroll position as the user scrolls up and down FlatList?

Comment: Oh I just understood what you are trying to achieve, so the line moves with the scroll. The easiest way would be to render it in the items, is that a viable option for your ui?

Comment: Yea I did try to think of just adding to the items themselves.. They are a few challenges with that approach tho.. First is that we only need one rendered at any point in time -- this could probably be solved by only rendering this item at a fixed index... But that brings up another challenge which is that off screen items are not rendered (for performance optimizations) so we'd have to somehow move this index to follow the visible window. Doesn't seem impossible but very tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working demo of what it sounds like you're trying to achieve: https://sketch.expo.io/BkreW1che. You can click "preview" to see it in your browser.

And here's the main code you need to measure the height of the ListView and place the indicator on top of it (visit the link above to see the full source):

```
  handleLayout(event) {
    const { y, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;

    // Now we know how tall the ListView is; let's put the indicator in the middle.
    this.setState({ indicatorOffset: y + (height / 2) });
  }

  renderIndicator() {
    const { indicatorOffset } = this.state;

    // Once we know how tall the ListView is, put the indicator on top.
    return indicatorOffset ? (
      <View style={[{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, top: indicatorOffset }]} />
    ) : null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          onLayout={(event) => this.handleLayout(event)}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
        {this.renderIndicator()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Edit: I now understand that you want the indicator to scroll along with the list. That's a simple change from above, just add an `onScroll` listener to the ListView: https://sketch.expo.io/HkEjDy92e

```
  handleScroll(event) {
    const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;

    // Keep the indicator at the same position in the list using this offset.
    this.setState({ scrollOffset: y });
  },
```

With this change, the indicator actually seems to lag behind a bit because of the delay in the `onScroll` callback.

If you want better performance, you might consider rendering the indicator as part of your `renderRow` method instead. For example, if you know the indicator should appear at 10:30 am, then you would render it right in the middle of your 10am row.

Comment: This is awesome!!...Thanks for the demo too... gonna give rendering inside renderRow a shot since performance is really everything at this point.

Comment: The scrolling performance should be pretty poor if you render for each one.
Might be better to use Animated.event with native animated driver and then interpolate it for the red element's `translateY`